# Advantages of Ionic lazy loading

Tags: ionic-framework, loading, ionic3

Did a simple Google search:
https://www.google.com/search?q=advantages+of+ionic+lazy+loading

And couldn't really find a detailed description of the advantages of lazy loading. Anyone care to explain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Long story short: (startup)-**performance**!

*The underlying problem:*

When you do a cold start of your app (no resume) the webview engine needs to load, parse and interpret a lot of javascript to become useable. The top high-end devices are mostly capable of doing so in a kind of acceptable timeframe but on hardware which is a few years old or simply not equipped with enough CPU power this may take a while.

Another problem (especially when developing PWAs) is network speed, with WiFi or 4G it is no problem (but also far from ideal!) at all to quickly download a few MBs of javascript. But on a slow 3G connection you can go and drink a coffee while waiting until your app becomes interactive.

*Lazy-loading to the rescue!*

So how can we minimize the effort to make the app interactive faster? We split up our heavy main bundle into many smaller bundles. So if we start our app now, only the bare minimum of javascript needed for the first page has to be fetched and parsed. Every time we need a specific feature (a page) we do the loading just in time (lazy) instead of ahead of time (eager). By always just fetching a small chunk of javascript when needed the performance gain will be huge for some devices but will definitly noticeable on every device.

If you implement lazy-loading in Ionic3 your code also becomes more modular and maintainable because you will create a self-contained Angular module for every `IonicPage` and by pushing a string onto the nav-stack instead of an actual page instance you remove a lot of dependencies (imports) in your code.

Comment: Good explanation.+1. But you need to mention about the `html/css` too on each and every page. You just mentioned about `javascript` only. Due to the lazy loading, we do not need to load a lot of `html/css` code upfront.

Comment: Thanks for your input! But I did not mention it on purpose because css is not affected by lazy-loading (it is fetched upfront by loading `main.css`) and the html templates of the components are embedded as strings in the javascript bundles.

Comment: Aha.. Good to know about it. `html templates of the components are embedded as strings in the javascript bundles` Hope this is due to `AOT`?

Comment: You can check this very easy by looking through the `www` folder, everything that is needed to render the webview is in there. Not AoT compilation specifically, but the Angular compiler yes. AoT and JiT are basically the same compiler, one executed at buildtime and the other one at runtime. From the angular [docs](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler): _"The compiler inlines external HTML templates and CSS style sheets within the application JavaScript, eliminating separate ajax requests for those source files."_

Comment: Thanks David! Makes sense :)

Comment: Glad I could be of help!